# Headers missing from okhttpclient using custom interceptor (but work if I add statically/dynamically)

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I am having a bit of an issue with logging my headers.

Here is my class that implements interceptor:

```
public class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private SessionManagement sessionManagement;

    public AuthInterceptor(Context ctx) {
        this.sessionManagement = new SessionManagement(ctx);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();

        // if token saved, add to request
        String token = sessionManagement.getSessionToken();

        if (token != null) {
            requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        }

        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

And here is my ApiClient class:

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "some/url";

    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(Context context) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            AuthInterceptor authInterceptor = new AuthInterceptor(context);

            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            ClearableCookieJar cookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                    .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

I feel these have been implemented correctly, but I am still unable to see the headers in my logs:

```
2023-01-26 13:35:53.361  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  --> POST http://.../loginuser.php
2023-01-26 13:35:53.361  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2023-01-26 13:35:53.361  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Content-Length: 41
2023-01-26 13:35:53.361  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  {"email":"t@t.com","password":"test1234"}
2023-01-26 13:35:53.361  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  --> END POST (41-byte body)
2023-01-26 13:35:53.458  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  <-- 200 OK http://.../loginuser.php (96ms)
2023-01-26 13:35:53.458  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2023 12:35:54 GMT
2023-01-26 13:35:53.458  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.1.10
2023-01-26 13:35:53.458  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.10
2023-01-26 13:35:53.458  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
2023-01-26 13:35:53.458  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
2023-01-26 13:35:53.458  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Pragma: no-cache
2023-01-26 13:35:53.458  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=l08iqa7cs8tvt1bfnijkl1r7d8; path=/
2023-01-26 13:35:53.459  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Content-Length: 194
2023-01-26 13:35:53.459  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
2023-01-26 13:35:53.459  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Connection: Keep-Alive
2023-01-26 13:35:53.459  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2023-01-26 13:35:53.459  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  {"status_code":200,"auth_token":"TEMPTOKEN","user":{"id":"30","full_name":null,"username":"t","password_hash":"$2y","email":"t@t.com"}}
2023-01-26 13:35:53.459  7841-7924  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.releasesapp              I  <-- END HTTP (194-byte body)
```

Additionally, if I completely comment out my OkHttpClient (as well as the .client(okHttpClient) line), my log still shows okhttpclient. Is this normal?

Appreciate any help I can get with this.

Answer (score 0):

try this I hope helpful you

```
 private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request request = chain.request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                 .addHeader("Authorization",sessionManagement.getSessionToken() != null ? "Bearer " + sessionManagement.getSessionToken(): "")
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        })
        .addInterceptor(logging)
        .build();
```

Comment: Hi, I added the timeout to my okhttpcient as well as the two additional headers to my AuthInterceptor, but I am still unable to see the header

Comment: Using just the code you suggested and not using my AuthInterceptor, I am able to see headers on my request, but not in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Interceptor that you set works in sequence that you set

It means if you set `authInterceptor` before `logging` then first `authInterceptor` executed and then `logging` will start to print so here you just need to change sequence

From

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                    .build();
```

To

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
                    .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                    .build();
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like I am still unable to see the header even after switching them around ;(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe my token was missing, because the original sequence seems to work fine now that I moved the code outside of the if statement (for now):

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                    .build();
```

And my AuthInterceptor now looks like this:

```
requestBuilder.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                      .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                      .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

However, I was wondering why I wasn't getting a header with the json response. Is this supposed to also be handled by the Interceptor?

For the time being, I went ahead and added headers to my php code before passing back a response. I am not sure if this is how it's actually supposed to be done.

```
header("Accept: application/json");
            header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
            header("Authorization: Bearer " . $response['auth_token']);


            echo json_encode($response);
            exit;
```